# How can I recover my HDD which is no longer recognized by my system?

Tags: hard-disk

My system was acting weird, so I booted into a live USB and ran `fsck` on my internal HDD. But I got a bunch of errors in fsck, and then the drive wasn't showing up in Files, in gnome-disks, or anywhere. When I rebooted, my BIOS was telling me it couldn't find the disk at all. I couldn't even select my Windows partition to boot from—it just couldn't find the disk at all.

I took out the disk and put it in an external enclosure, to see if I could fix it. But sure enough, even on another system, it's not being recognized.

I'm on NixOS if that makes any difference. Here's the output I get from `dmesg`:

```
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop kernel: usb 2-3: new SuperSpeedPlus Gen 2 USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop kernel: usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0562, bcdDevice= 2.06
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop kernel: usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop kernel: usb 2-3: Product: SSK Storage
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop kernel: usb 2-3: Manufacturer: SSK
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop kernel: usb 2-3: SerialNumber: DF56419883A9B
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop kernel: scsi host0: uas
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop kernel: scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SSK                       0206 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop mtp-probe[1276]: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/usb2/2-3"
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop mtp-probe[1276]: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop mtp-probe[1281]: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/usb2/2-3"
Mar 07 18:42:50 jon-laptop mtp-probe[1281]: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Mar 07 18:43:00 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
Mar 07 18:43:47 jon-laptop kernel: ...
Mar 07 18:43:47 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: tag#25 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Mar 07 18:43:47 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: tag#25 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
Mar 07 18:43:47 jon-laptop kernel: scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
Mar 07 18:43:47 jon-laptop kernel: usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeedPlus Gen 2 USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Mar 07 18:43:47 jon-laptop kernel: scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
Mar 07 18:43:57 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: tag#25 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Mar 07 18:43:57 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: tag#25 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
Mar 07 18:43:57 jon-laptop kernel: scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeedPlus Gen 2 USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: ready
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 38 02 00 38
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 07 18:43:58 jon-laptop kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

But nothing appears in the usual places: Files, `sudo fdisk -l`, `lsblk`, `lsusb`, or related commands.

I'm guessing something went very wrong. Is there a way I can fix this drive and/or recover my data?

Comment: You can try in a different port and with a different cable and also, in different computer but if it still isn't recognized, the drive is most likely done. Hopefully, there is a backup.

Comment: And to elaborate: both the BIOS and the kernel cannot coax any sign of life out of the drive. Which means likely something is broken on the drive that prevents it from communicating with the computer, if it's not completely dead in the first place (do you hear it spinning up?).

Comment: It really sounds like that drive is dead. At this point your options are basically find a data recovery specialist (500 to 1,500 GBP last time I checked) or abandon the data.